# Java Char Array Appending Error

Tags: java, arrays, char, append

In Java, I have been trying to append a string to a Char Array. I am using the code:

```
list = (new String(list) + word).toCharArray();
```

With list being the char array, and word being a string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Comment: code is valid to do the toCharArray if list and word are String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

- list is `char[]` or `byte[]` (or `String`, `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer` but that's a bit off-topic)
- `list != null`

Explanation:

- the `String` one-argument constructor only takes the types I've listed above
- `new String(null)` is an ambiguous call to the `String` one-argument constructor
- `word` can be any type, including a `null` object (in which case it will be represented as `"null"`)

Comment: Thanks - I was using a null string

Answer (score 0):

what is the list type? `Character[]` or `char[]`.

Since arrays are objects, they are not interchangeable.

For this situation list must be `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could show us the exact error what you get. By using the below code I can get some output without any error.

```
    String word="hi";
    char[] list=null;
    if(list!=null)
        list = (new String(list) + word).toCharArray();
    else
        list = word.toCharArray();
    for(char ch: list)
    System.out.println("List: "+ch);
```